Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:25) File was processed with these loaders:
Trying to use leaflet with react Canary, but it cannot compile. It seems to be having issues with the babel-loader / webpack
I have tried adding changing the version of leaflet, i tried changing the browser target to
"browserslist": [
   ">0.2%",
  "not dead",
  "not op_mini all"
],


The only thing that seemed to work was reverting back to normal react, but this broke other things inside of the project.
Here is my current package.json
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.25.4",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.24.7",
    "@react-leaflet/core": "^2.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^9.2.1",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "leaflet": "1.7.1",
    "react": "^19.0.0-rc-a99d8e8d-20240916",
    "react-dom": "^19.0.0-rc-a99d8e8d-20240916",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
    "react-router": "^6.26.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.26.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.0-next.38",
    "redbox-react": "^1.6.0",
    "styled-components": "5.3.10",
    "universal-cookie": "^7.2.0",
    "util": "^0.12.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.9.12"
  }
}



This question is similar to: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (257:106) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
